# Need to hide tablix when there is no data coming from different datasets. How to use or condition for visibility

Tags: reporting-services, report

Report has multiple tablix and each tablix is getting data  from different dataset.I was trying to hide the tablix when there is no data.if only 1 tablix has data it should show only 1 tablix. And if data is there then only page break will come as there are multiple individuals reports. Need help

Comment: Did you check the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the tablix by selecting the tablix, in designer, and/or properties Window , by selecting the tablix and pressing `ctrl+F4`, 

Then you can go to `Visibility` section of report tablix and in its value put the expression like

```
=IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!FieldName.Value)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Make sure you select the tablix properly, and put, therein, in its Visibility, the expression,

**Edit**

The better way to go for it would be to try something like:-

```
 =IIF(CountRows("YourDataSetName") < 1, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: you may need to replace `FieldName` with your field from `Dataset`

Comment: I have done the same but i want the same when data is comjng from 2 datasets. Or condition is not working 

Comment: can you elaborate, what you mean by  _when data is coming from two datasets ?_

Comment: you have to set the visibility condition in `every tablix` that you want to make `visible/invisible` , and you _have_ two datasets for that, right.. So, jus replace Dataset name with that of your datasets, that should do it.. reply back so that problem is resolved ..

Comment: @DivyaJain Can you see is it working now ..?? Check the above comments ..

Comment: Looking at this as well.  I have one dataset feeding 3 tablixi (?) depending on the value in one column.  So the dataset will always have a count, even if those records are not used in that particular table.